# I want to access a subscriptable object in python Programming

Tags: python, list

I want to retrieve data i.e `symbol`, `id`, etc,

```
List = api.get_activities()

AccountActivity({   'activity_type': 'FILL',
    'cum_qty': '10',
    'id': '20211227093208266::0e4e8144-e4ce-4b0f-af54-f35c575e2adb',
    'leaves_qty': '0',
    'order_id': '4746c3ac-a62b-4208-9098-de0d3a05f071',
    'order_status': 'filled',
    'price': '137.16',
    'qty': '3',
    'side': 'buy',
    'symbol': 'QDEL',
    'transaction_time': '2021-12-27T14:32:08.266871Z',
    'type': 'fill'})

List[1]

List[1]["symbol"]
```

I am facing this error.

> 'AccountActivity' object is not subscriptable

Comment: is that the string representation of `List` or what? have you tried accessing it somewhat like this: `List.symbol`? and why do you use `1`? list indexes start from `0` so that would make more sense, but `AccountActivity` clearly doesn't support that at all and so you could try `List['symbol']` but apparently the class doesn't define `__getitem__` method, so that could be the string representation of `__dict__`, meaning that you would need to use sth like `List.name_of_attribute`, for example, `List.symbol`

Comment: What is `api`? For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including complete code and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). You can [edit]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].